# Static assert failure while using boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor()

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, gzip, static-assert

I have a large compressed file that I have to read and periodically need to change the position in the file when reading, that's why I want to make it seekable. I have two versions to declare the object, but both of them don't give the necessary result.

**VERSION 1**

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_stream< boost::iostreams::input_seekable > fstrm;
fstrm.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
fstrm.push(boost::iostreams::file_source(varFile.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in));
```

In this version I got compile-error stating this ***boost_1_72_0/boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp:68:21: error: static assertion failed: ( is_convertible< BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME iostreams::category_of::type, Mode >::value )
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((*** complaining the line

`fstrm.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());`

I removed the line, and it compiled, but `std::getline()` gives non-human readable data, which is logical, since the input file is compressed.
I tried another version mentioned below.

**VERSION 2**

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream fstrm;        
fstrm.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());        
fstrm.push(boost::iostreams::file_source(varFile.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in));
        ...
boost::iostreams::seek(fstrm, -(currentLine.length() + 1), BOOST_IOS::cur);
```

In this case, I receive exception ***no random access: iostream error***

What's the accurate way of declaring the object to be able to read lines human-readable way and `seek` through the file with no exceptions?